# React js TypeError: Cannot read property 'rfpid' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, hibernate

hello everyone i m getting this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rfpid' of undefined

so i need to get all the data existe in my database :

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/aspsort/all")
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) =>{
      this.setState({listaspsort : data})
    })  
  }
```

the data :

```
{this.state.listaspsort.map((listaspsort)=>(
  <tr key={listaspsort.id} >  

    <th scope="row">{listaspsort.id}</th>

    <td>{this.listaspsort.rfpid.id}</td>
    <td>{listaspsort.requestid}</td>
    <td>{listaspsort.aspart}</td>
    <td>{listaspsort.aspname}</td>
    <td>  {listaspsort.asporganisation} </td>
    <td>  {listaspsort.aspsort} </td>
  </tr> ))
}
```

please what i should to do to resolve this error

Comment: I think `<td>{this.listaspsort.rfpid.id}</td>`should be `<td>{this.state.listaspsort.rfpid.id}</td>` or `<td>{listaspsort.rfpid.id}</td>`. Also, you should do undefined check because API fetch returns data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this.listaspsort is undefined. As you are iterating on this.state.listaspsort and the key you are using to map is called listaspsort I guess that is what you need to use:

```
<td>{listaspsort.rfpid.id}</td>
```

Anyway, as we can not see the result you are getting from axios that is only a guess. If you provide it I will probably be able to help you better.